# Parse notifications not working in trigger.io

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, trigger.io

I am trying to get my trigger.io app to receive push notifications from parse. I've set up an account with Parse.com, installed and configured the parse trigger.io module and added the relevant setup code to my app.

Here is the code from my client app:

```
    forge.parse.installationInfo(success, error);

    function success(info){
       forge.logging.log("installation: "+JSON.stringify(info));
    }

    function error(info){
       forge.logging.log("Parse error! "+JSON.stringify(info));
    }

    forge.parse.push.subscribe("beta-testers",function () {
       forge.logging.info("subscribed to beta-tester push notifications!");
    },function (err) {
       forge.logging.error("error: "+ JSON.stringify(err));
    });

    forge.event.messagePushed.addListener(function (msg) {
      forge.logging.log(JSON.stringify(msg));
    });
```

The app appears to successfully connect to Parse.com.
It logs all the relevant confirmation messages:
(I have purposely blanked out my device ID)

```
[INFO] Pausing webview while application not focussed.
[INFO] Checking for reload update.
[INFO] Android remote debugging disabled.
[INFO] Android hardware acceleration enabled.
[INFO] Loading live page in webview: http://10.56.2.49:31337/src/index.html
[INFO] Application in focus, resuming webview.
[INFO] No reload update available.
[INFO] [FORGE] 'installation: {"id":"XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"}'
[INFO] [FORGE] 'subscribed to beta-tester push notifications!'
[INFO] Checking for reload update.
[INFO] No reload update available.
```

The devices I am testing (AVD emulator + .apk on phone) both seem to register on parse.com; when I choose recipients to send a notification to the blue menu bar reads "This will be sent to 2 devices".

So as far as I can tell everything is set up correctly. 
However if I send the notification neither of my devices receives it.
The forge.io log remains quiet and the "Pushes Sent" column on the parse.com dashboard reads "0" for all my sends.

I've reached the stage where I'm not sure how to debug this any further.

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antoine van Gelder at Trigger.io support managed to help me solve this problem.
I was using Forge serve to test the app instead of running an actual compiled instance of the app.

Thank you Antoine!